# Substituting one cup creamy peanut butter with peanut butter Reese's chips to make peanut butter swirl brownies box made recipe

Tags: substitutions, brownies, peanut-butter

On the side of the chocolate fudge brownie mix family size box there's a peanut butter swirl brownies recipe and I'm trying to figure out how to substitute the one cup of creamy peanut butter with Reese's peanut butter chips if that's possible even if I have two previously melt them or something to get it to work I know chips are meant to stay solid and whole while in oven during high heat that's why I'm asking because the person that went to the store didn't read the side recipe and assumed that it called for peanut butter chips or that it didn't matter what form the peanut butter came in and so they got a pack of reeses chips and we currently don't have any regular creamy peanut butter like the recipe calls for.

Comment: I don’t think it is a possible substitution. I feel that the recipe aims for a special consistency/wetness for the brownies. If you substitute a creamy ingredient for a solid one you might end up with quite a compact block of brownie rather than a fudgy one

Comment: Welcome to the site. How is the peanut butter used? Is it mixed in with the batter, or added later as a swirl?

Comment: Welcome to SA!  In the future, the following will help folks provide you with better answers:  name the box mix you're using, provide notes on quantities and ingredients for the peanut swirl variation, and let us know what kinds of results are acceptable.

Comment: Please break your question into sentences. It's quite difficult to read as it is.

Answer (score 5):

Why not just add the chips to the brownies, and have peanut butter chip brownies?  Those would be excellent on their own, and you don't have to figure out how to make melted peanut butter chips behave like wet peanut butter.